# Is there software with CAS to solve drawn electrical circuit in form of differential equations which describes that electrical circuit?

Tags: differential, state-space, equation

Is there any software with Computer Algebra System to solve drawn electrical circuit in the form of differential equations which describe that electrical circuit? Or to write symbolic solution (matrices) of state space equation?

Comment: Do you understand how to use Laplace and how it relates to many linear circuits? I guess not?

Comment: @Andyaka I know how to use Laplace to solve circuits by hand but I'm asking is there any software system as Wolfram Mathematica for solving electrical circuits in form that it can display differential equations of given circuit. I'm asking that because it can benefit students for teaching and practicing solving circuits like for example: https://github.com/pssoh/SALECx